# Cakephp Multiple Table search in container behaviour

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

hello I want to get results from multiple tables using the keyword which user has typed. The problem I am having is I don't know how can I do search on that table which is getting through `contain`

Here's my query

```
public function getGigPostBasedOnSearch($keyword){
        $this->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
        return $this->find('all', array(

            'contain' => array(
              'User','UserInfo', 'GigPostAndCategory.Category','Location','GigPostAndCalender'

            ),
              'conditions' => array(
                  'AND' => array( 
                      'GigPost.active' => 1,
               'OR' => array(

            array('GigPost.title LIKE' => '%'.$keyword.'%'),
            array('GigPost.description LIKE' => '%'.$keyword.'%'),
            array('Location.location_string LIKE' => '%'.$keyword.'%'),


        )
)
                 //'OrderGigPost.request' => 0
            ),
            'order' => 'GigPost.gig_post_id DESC',

            'recursive' => 0
        ));
    }
```

This query works fine. I want to search keyword in category table also.I want to do something like this

```
array('Category.cat_name LIKE' => '%'.$keyword.'%')
```

Please help me how can I search in Category table as well

Thank you

Model GigPost.php

```
<?php



class GigPost extends AppModel
{
    public $useTable = 'gig_post';
    public $primaryKey = 'gig_post_id';

public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
'Category' =>
array(
'className' => 'Category',
'joinTable' => 'gigpost_category',
'foreignKey' => 'gig_post_id',
'associationForeignKey' => 'cat_id',
'unique' => true,
)
);
    public $hasOne = array(
        'Location' => array(
            'className'     => 'Location',
            'foreignKey'    => 'gig_post_id',
            'conditions' => array('GigPost.gig_post_id = Location.gig_post_id')
        ));


    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'fields' => array('User.user_id','User.email','User.active')

        ),
        'UserInfo' => array(
            'className' => 'UserInfo',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',


        )

    );







    public function getGigPostBasedOnSearch($keyword){
        $this->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
        return $this->find('all', array(

            'contain' => array(
                'User','UserInfo', 'GigPostAndCategory.Category'=>array(
                    'conditions'=>array(

                        'OR' => array(

                            array('Category.cat_name' => '%'.$keyword.'%'),
                        ),


                    )
                ),'Location','GigPostAndCalender'

            ),
            'conditions' => array(
                'AND' => array(
                    'GigPost.active' => 1,
                    'OR' => array(


                        array('GigPost.title LIKE' => '%'.$keyword.'%'),
            array('GigPost.description LIKE' => '%'.$keyword.'%'),
            array('Location.location_string LIKE' => '%'.$keyword.'%'),
           // array('Category.cat_name LIKE' => '%'.$keyword.'%'),


        )
)
                 //'OrderGigPost.request' => 0
            ),
            'order' => 'GigPost.gig_post_id DESC',

            'recursive' => 0
        ));
    }




}
```

Comment: What relationships have you defined for your models?

Comment: @drmonkeyninja I will update my question

Comment: @drmonkeyninja do you want me to add details of other models as well which are connected to this current one "gigpost"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that the relationship between `GigPost` and `Category` is HABTM, so when you use `contain` Cake has to do a separate query to retrieve the related categories as there is not a one-on-one association. To get round this you need to manually perform a join rather than `contain` the categories:-

```
$this->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'User', 'UserInfo', 'GigPostAndCategory.Category', 'Location', 'GigPostAndCalender'
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'gigpost_category',
            'alias' => 'GigPostCategory',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => 'GigPost.id = GigPostCategory.gig_post_id'
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'categories',
            'alias' => 'Category',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => 'Category.id = GigPostCategory.cat_id'
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'AND' => array( 
            'GigPost.active' => 1,
            'OR' => array(
                array('GigPost.title LIKE' => '%'.$keyword.'%'),
                array('GigPost.description LIKE' => '%'.$keyword.'%'),
                array('Location.location_string LIKE' => '%'.$keyword.'%'),
                array('Category.cat_name LIKE' => '%'.$keyword.'%'),
            )
        )
    ),
    'order' => 'GigPost.gig_post_id DESC',
    'group' => 'GigPost.id',
    'recursive' => 0
));
```

This ensures that the categories will be included with the data returned by the primary query.

You will probably need to modify the `joins` array a bit as you don't appear to be using Cake naming conventions for your table so I am not sure what you have named things. However, this should put you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you very much @drmonkeyninja. You are awesome. You are great. I am in your debt now. thank you again